# ill-formed log in Loki

Tags: go, kubernetes, logging, grafana, grafana-loki

I'm using zerolog in golang, which outputs json formatted log, the app is running on k8s, and has cri-o format as following.
[actual log screenshot on Grafana loki](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1qMe.png)

My question is, since there's some non-json text prepended to my json log, I can't seem to effectively query the log, one example is, when I tried to pipe the log into logfmt, exceptions were thrown.

What I want is to be able to query into the sub field of the json.
My intuition is to maybe for each log, only select the parts from `{` (start of the json), then maybe I can do more interesting manipulation. I'm a bit stuck and not sure what's the best way to proceed.

Any help and comments is appreciated.

Comment: The log line is in JSON format, why are you piping it to `logfmt` ? You should use the JSON parser, see https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/logql/log_queries/#json

Comment: @marco.m hello, thank you for the response, as you can see the log is in the following format: <plain text> <valid json>, when I pipe this log to `json` parser (on Grafana), it also throw exception. Since together with the <plain text>, the whole log is not a valid json

Answer (score 1):

after some head scratching, problem solved.

As I'm directly using the promtail setup from here https://raw.githubusercontent.com/grafana/loki/master/tools/promtail.sh

And within this setup, the default parser is docker, but we need to change it to `cri`, afterwards, the logs are properly parsed as json in my Grafana dashboard